# Emoji encoding for Android - SERVER - WEB

Tags: java, php, android, unicode, emoji

I'm trying to implement Emoji for my android app and website.

In application i am using standard android emojies.

Because i need cyrillic characters i found solution in sending string from app to server through next 3 steps:
 1. Use escapeText = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(text);
 2. Use textToSend = URLEncoder.encode(escapeText, "UTF-8");
 3. And finally send "textToSend" to PHP-Server through GET-request.

I'm store this string in MySQL(UTF8mb4_general_ci)
For string "Русский English *emoji*"
it's
"\u0420\u0443\u0441\u0441\u043A\u0438\u0439 English \uD83D\uDE0E"

For show this string in app i'm parse json_encode from PHP-Server and use:
string = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(string);

That's how my app can save and show cyrillic chars, also i can read this string and show on website :)

So the question is - **What should i do** to convert string with emoji from html-form to encoding like that - \u0420\u0443\u0441\u0441\u043A\u0438\u0439 English \uD83D\uDE0E

Sorry for my English :)

Comment: Skip step 1. A common way is: encode to UTF-8, then use percent-encoding to encode the resulting bytes. I'm guessing that is what step 2 does.